# tomcat serving cached alias

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, caching, compilation

I'm trying to serve a jsp file at two locations.  (The jsp file uses `request.getRequestURI()` to decide which content to serve.)  I'm using a `web.xml` below.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <!--no / here or url pattern will need //-->
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/advanced/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

While it works fine, tomcat seems to cache the jsp at `/advanced/` and not the one served at `/`.  How can I fix this so that it is the same for both?  (I don't want to cache for development, only for production.)

I can see only one java file in tomcat's `work` directory, so I imagine this issue is not related to the fact that I am using jsp, but related to the way I have set up the mapping.

**EDIT:** I have checked the headers in curl and I can see that tomcat is not sending a `Last-Modified` header, so I don't see why any browser would cache it.  Also, with curl, I can see that / is updated as I update the jsp, but /advanced/ is not.

**EDIT2:** I spent some time in `org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler#isOutDated(boolean)`, and I've found that only the first URL that I visit is the one that is marked outDated.  The second URL I visit is never marked outDated.  So it's as if tomcat keeps two instances of `JspServlet` but share the same outDated information for the file, so when one `JspServlet` marks it as outDated and sets `reload`, the second JspServlet never recompiles it nor serves the recompiled version.  How can I fix/workaround this?

Comment: I don't think this is a cache problem. Please try debugging it

Comment: i wouldn't know where to put a breakpoint

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the java code that creates the view. say for example - Servlets

Comment: if you think it is cached and you press ctrl-f5 does it re-load ?

Comment: I don't have any servlets.

Comment: It does reload.  I have checked in firefox and chrome.  / reloads fine, but /advanced/ loads a stale copy.

Comment: What do you use to render the view? If you think it is a cache problem. Then, you can look on the cache-headers

Comment: please show how you are calling the code (from browser which url)

Comment: there is no code.  there is only jsp -> tomcat -> browser.

Comment: @Jayen As a sidenote, Writing scriptlets is bad. Please don't perform any logical operations in the JSP. It is just for presentation layer.

Comment: @Jayen what urls are you calling?

Comment: @Keerthivasan is there another way to have conditional HTML based on the URL?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `http://localhost:9090/` and `http://localhost:9090/advanced/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it's a bug in tomcat, [open a bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57845).  The developers are often quick to triage bugs.  This bug has just been [fixed](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1675602) and will be in 7.0.62 & 8.0.22.